# Auto Injection with typhoon + swift

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, typhoon

I'm using typhoon in a swift project, as far as i understand i have to map all injections explicitly in a TyphoonAssembly like this:

```
 public dynamic func appDelegate() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppDelegate.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.injectProperty("cityDao", with:self.coreComponents.cityDao())
        definition.injectProperty("rootViewController", with:self.rootViewController())
    }
}
```

this seems hard to manage, and very fragile (when refactoring).

I see that there is support for auto injection (matching by types) here:
https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Auto-injection-(Objective-C)
but this is for objetive c.

Does anyone know of a way i can wire up the injection without explicitly registering props with their name as string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Typhoon creator here).

Typhoon is a dynamic, introspective dependency injection container , and uses the Objective-C run-time. There are the following limitations, when it comes to Swift:

- With Objective-C it avoids magic strings, allowing the use of ordinary IDE refactoring tools, however in Swift selectors ***are*** magic strings.
- The Objective-C runtime only provides type information for properties, not method or initializer parameters. So only properties can support auto-wiring of any kind (macros, implicit, etc).
- There is no annotation or macro system for Swift, (but it does have 1st class functions).

You can instruct Typhoon to auto-wire a property in Swift using the following:

```
 public dynamic func appDelegate() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppDelegate.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.injectProperty("cityDao")
        definition.injectProperty("rootViewController")
    }
}
```

. . and this will match by type, just as the auto-wiring Objective-C macros do. However this does not avoid specifying the name of the property to be injected. ***There is no other way to do this in Swift.*** :(

Its worth mentioning there are additional limitations when using Typhoon with Swift:

- "Pure" Swift classes - not extending a Cocoa base class or declaring the `@objc` directive - don't support introspection, dynamic dispatch or dynamic method invocation. Typhoon only works with Cocoa classes.
- Swift protocols require the `@objc` directive.

Comment: @talarari You're very welcome. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but hopefully the approach to Di in Swift will improve as time goes on, either through Typhoon, language evolution or another "functional" DI lib. For the latter FiercyCrucible looks like its off to a fantastic start.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth reply!

i'll take a look FieryCrucible to see if it better suits my needs.

regarding property names, couldn't i use the reflect method to get all properties for a class and register them with typhoon ?
As mentioned here:
[link]http://freecake.yayuhh.com/simple-reflection-in-swift/

I would still need to register the class but that could save the magic strings part.

i'm rather new to ios development so i might be off here.

Comment: @talarari We *could* provide a 'by convention' style of property injection. The reflect method wouldn't actually help, since all it can do is enumerate properties, which is useful for tool support. But to actually perform an injection requires runtime method invocation. Fortunately the ObjC runtime can list properties for Swift classes, if they're extending `NSObject`, as well as dynamically invoke methods. . . so it comes down to agreeing on a 'by convention' approach. Would you like to open an issue?

Comment: yeah sure, i'll open an issue on your github.
for now i could decide on my own convention and write one generic property wiring method. 
for instance have injected properties start with some prefix.

Comment: Yes we could use Typhoon's DefinitionPostProcessor system to make it an optional plugin. Using a property name prefix is an option for Swift.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use Typhoon's auto-wiring in Swift.

The auto-wiring in ObjC is like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) InjectedClass(ViewController) rootViewController;
```

We can survey the definition of the macro, InjectedClass

```
#define InjectedProtocol(aProtocol) TyphoonInjectedObject<aProtocol>*
#define InjectedClass(aClass) aClass<TyphoonInjectedProtocol>*
```

Thus, the auto-wiring in Swift is like

```
var rootViewController: (ViewController & TyphoonInjectedProtocol)?
```

Comment: Nice one Xanadu. At last you can try https://pilgrim.ph now too, if you like.